# Could we celebrate Mass together?

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering:

> How many Christianity.SE members would be interested in celebrating an online Mass together?

I suppose any Christian denomination would suffice, as long as we can agree to a mutually acceptable time. (In light of the fact that some members live in the Eastern Hemisphere, this might be challenging.)

The thought occurred to me for two reasons:

1. Other SE communities have organized get-togethers [in the physical world](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/stack-overflow-worldwide-meetups-2012); so why can't we do it in virtual world?
2. The opportunity to congregate and worship together might help us build a sense of community on Christianity.SE.

So please, tell me what you think. Is this feasible?

Furthermore, do we have any preachers among us? I for one, [am always in the mood for an outstanding homilist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9852/1100).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what an "online mass" would look like, but I'm certain I wouldn't attend.

That's not to discourage others from doing so, if they feel it would be beneficial or interesting in some way, but it just feels weird to me.

Online church (especially among (semi-)strangers) feels weirder than online dating, IMHO.

I don't mean this post to be negative--but you asked what others think, so that's what I think

Comment: Interesting. The American Catholic Church is facing a severe priest shortage, so if you live in a rural location, you might have to get used to it. http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33626/1100

Comment: @JimG.: I'm not Catholic, nor in America, so I don't think that's likely to affect me.

Answer (score 4):

On what basis would I want to be united to arbitrary members of this community when we acknowledge that the site is about multiple contradictory religions? Whose God will we worship? Whose liturgy will we follow? Whose preaching will be deemed acceptable?

Comment: Legitimate questions. Use of the word Mass suggests Catholic leanings, but the OP specifically says he's cool with whatever (I assume there are limits though). So the question for you now is *if* it is a liturgy or preacher that you find agreeable would you attend the online Mass?

Comment: Multiple contradictory "religions" or "Denominations" -- which do you mean?

Comment: @korvin Well for example, some people would like to invoke the intercession of Mary, and others consider that a grave heresy.

Comment: Those aren't different *religions* but I think I'll stop there. And this is sort of old, as a question/topic.

Answer (score 2):

If there were to be some kind of on-line meet up of this kind, I would suggest that you'd need to go for something that is intrinsically ecumenical. Mass doesn't get you very far with that. Taize prayer might be a better option?