# Why is this stack exchange never about christian issues?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am very concerned about this "forum" and I believe it to be a lie.

This is a open rebuke. **None of the topics** I have seen are ever discussed by Christians (I have been a Christian for about 25 years) **I believe this forum is Satanic and was simply created to AVOID creating a space where Christians get ask and get answers.**

For example everything is red below is utterly nonsense and I can say it has nothing to do with any of:

- what Jesus Taught
- the bible
- Apologetics
- Strong argumentation
- Counter arguments to supposed refutations

[image: ubb]

Comment: have you read the [what topics can I ask about here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) post?

Comment: The very conditions which permit you to ask your question (and permit it to be asked in the manner in which you asked it) are those which permit every user who wishes  (whatever their persuasion) to participate.

Comment: @Test: Let's organize a site-wide Mass and chat about it over pastries and coffee afterwards. Just like we would've done in person before COVID-19. https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4070/1100

Answer (score 11):

Can I suggest that your view of what "Christian issues" consist of is far too narrow: it basically boils down to two things: the Bible, and apologetics. We aren't so narrow here. Instead you'll see questions from all the subject areas that you'd study at a Bible college:

1. Biblical texts and exegesis
2. Systematic and Biblical theology
3. Church history and historical theology
4. Ethics and philosophy
5. Practical and pastoral theology
6. And yes, apologetics, along with comparative religion, etc.

I hope you have the humility to reconsider your assessment of this site. Why would you call a question asking who first said that there are four important truths about the Bible a "Satanic" question?? Look, even if you disagree with any of those aspects (sufficency, clarity, authority, necessity) let me put it to you that it's not a Christian response to call other Christians who do support those descriptions "Satanic".

Lots of Christians don't see a lot of value in Historical Theology, which is a lot of what we do on this site. You've probably heard the saying that those who ignore history are doomed to repeat it, and that's just as true for the history of Christianity. Let me leave you with [eight important reasons from Gregg Allison for why Christians should study Historical Theology](https://timchester.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/why-study-historical-theology/):

> 1. Historical theology helps the church distinguish orthodoxy from heresy.
> 2. Historical theology provides sound biblical interpretation and theological formulations.
> 3. Historical theology presents stellar examples of faith, love, courage, hope, obedience and mercy.
> 4. Historical theology protects against the individualism that is rampant today among Christians.
> 5. Historical theology not only helps the church understand the historical development of its beliefs, but enables it to express those beliefs in contemporary form.
> 6. Historical theology encourages the church to focus on essentials, that is, to major on those areas that have been emphasized repeatedly throughout the history of the church.
> 7. Historical theology gives the church hope by providing assurance that Jesus is fulfilling his promise to his people [to build his church].
> 8. Historical theology [enables us] to enjoy a sense of belonging to the church of the past.

Answer (score 6):

This site is not a discussion forum, it is a Q&A site. What is on-topic and off-topic here is defined in such a way to try and make sure questions can be answered more or less opinion-free and objectively. The format of the site (Questions and answers, and quite limited comments) isn't really fit for a discussion, you are right to think that a forum (with a discussion thread) is a better format for that.

That being said, you will find examples of everything you mentioned. It just so happens that a lot of the meaningful questions don't fit this format. Nobody says this is the only site a christian should use. Saying it is satanic to ask about someone else beliefs, teachings, and traditions, or a question that ultimately isn't really that important is pretty rude, honestly. If you aren't satisfied with the questions, write better questions. If you aren't satisfied with the answers, write better answers.

Answer (score 4):

Just for your interest, these are the five most voted-up questions listed on SE-Christianity.

[image]

Comment: All are from 2011

Comment: @Autodidact  it would stand  to reason that the highest upvoted questions would be among the oldest

Comment: It would also stand to reason @Kris that the OP is referring to recent/active posts.

Comment: @Autodidact since the Op has a 1 reputation and has not been seen before this post it stands to reason that they have not viewed more than a few very recent posts. Yet they have passed judgement vociferously based on this minute sampling.

Answer (score 4):

This forum can't be Satanic, because this is not a forum!  It's a Q&A Site specifically designed not to be a forum.  It is supposed to be more of a spontaneously generated encyclopedia.  Each question is like an article in a catechism.  Each answer is not debated, it only is voted on and bubbles up to the top based on its own merit.  Everyone has their own criteria for merit, but there are deal breakers which include:

1. not answering the question.
2. being too vague.
3. not citing sources (or only citing sources that require interpretation )
4. vulgarity or spam

So it's not going to be able Christian issues very much. It's the new about.com guide to Christianity.

Answer (score 3):

I adhere to a Christian tradition that is not reflected by the majority of this site's users, nor is necessarily (and is at times specifically) considered "Christian" by other Christian traditions. Nevertheless...

**I thank God for this site; a site where people of differing Christian traditions and denominations may gather to discover both their commonalities and their differences.**

One of the earliest Meta questions I encountered was [Does this site have a novel approach to Christianity?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6358/35942). I have never forgotten Korvin Starmast's answer. Here's the leading paragraph:

> Because this community is not interested (collectively) in the great, 1900-year-long shouting match of "I'm right, you splitter!" — "No, I'm right, you heretic!" this is a unique internet space where I can engage warmly with my fellow believers from across the denominational spectrum, not argue with them. That gets saved for the rants in chat, or the continual attempts at 'gotcha questions' by a variety of people posting questions. Likewise with some non-believers who participate with good intention.

- This site is NOT a site where people can refute, rebuke, reject, or otherwise express hate toward ________________ (fill in the blank with any denomination that isn't your own).
- This site IS a site where people can receive answers to questions about their own tradition or denomination.
- This site IS a site where people can learn about other denominations and traditions.

Two of this site's defining Meta posts are below. Please read them.

- [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1379/35942)
- [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/35942) (this amazing question and its answers should in no wise be judged by its title!)

Does this willingness to talk, rather than participate in "the great, 1900-year-long shouting match" make us satanic? No, it doesn't.

Comment: And it's worth pointing out that we can still ask highly challenging questions. I think we've found a constructive way of doing so. There are a lot of questions asking denomination A how their doctrine B can be compatible with passage or doctrine C. You can see their answers yourself and judge how satisfying they are, or sometimes the lack of an answer is answer enough.